# Unit of equilibrium constant in formula for Gibbs free energy change at arbitrary temperature

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics, equilibrium

We know the relation for Gibbs free energy change of a reaction at any stage and any temperature
$$\Delta G=\Delta G^{\circ}+RT\ln Q$$
where Q is reaction quotient. Subsequently, we get the rate constant as
$$\Delta G^{\circ}=-RT\ln k_{eq}$$
My question is how do we deal with the units of $k_{eq}$, for example, if we have the reaction
$$N_{2}+3H_{2}\rightleftharpoons2NH_{3}$$
Rate constant at equilibrium can be written in terms of partial pressure as
$$k_{p}=\frac{P_{NH_{3}}^{2}}{P_{N_{2}}\cdot P_{H_{2}}^{3}}$$
I could calculate partial pressure in Pascal, torr, bar and so on which will change $\Delta G$. Please give clarification on the convention as to how we write $k_{p}$ when partial pressures in different units change $k_{p}$ according to equation above

Comment: Have you tried searching on SE for 'equilibrium constant unit'? There are several questions which address this.

Comment: The partial pressures are in bars.

Comment: Why is it in bars? Is it convention or does it depend on the unit of the universal gas constant that we chose? @Chet Miller

Comment: The equilibrium constant has to be dimensionless because the argument to the log  has to be dimensionless. This means that each pressure has be made dimensionless by divided by 1 atm. or 1 bar, or 760 torr or whatever units you are using.

Comment: It is in bars because $\Delta  G^0$ is defined as the change in G from pure reactants at 1 bar to pure products at 1 bar.